# Cadastro no banco via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Boa tarde.

Sou iniciante no mundo da programação, e estou desenvolvendo um app web e estou tendo problemas para realizar um cadastro de vendas no banco de dados. O sistema deve inserir novos inputs para cadastrar mais de 1 produto por venda. Quando aperto o botão de cadastrar, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\narguile\components\cad_venda.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\narguile\components\cad_venda.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\narguile\components\cad_venda.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\narguile\components\cad_venda.php on line 14
>
> Data Inserted

Segue o meu formulário:

```
<div id="modal8" class="modal">

<div class="modal-content" id="design_modal">

    <div id="font_titulo_modal"> Cadastrar Venda </div>

    <div id="font_modal">

        <form name="venda" id="venda" action="components/cad_venda.php" method="POST">

            <div class="row" id="inputs_cad_venda">

                <div class="input-field col s8">

                    <input placeholder="Digite o produto" name="produto_venda" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="produto_venda">Produto</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s2">

                    <input placeholder="Digite a quantidade" name="quantidade_produto_venda" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="quantidade_produto_venda">Quantidade</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="inputs_adicionais"></div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col s4 center">

                    <button class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn fonte_button2 modal-trigger" type="submit" name="cadastra_venda"><i class="material-icons left">add_circle</i><div class="espaco2">Cadastrar Venda</div></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="col s2 center">

            <button class="btn-floating btn-large waves-light grey darken-3" id="add_produto_venda"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript no header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){  
var i=1;

$('#add_produto_venda').click(function(){

  i++;  
  $('#inputs_adicionais').append('<div class="row" id="inputs_cad_venda'+i+'"> <div class="input-field col s8"> <input placeholder="Digite o produto" name="produto_venda" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="produto_venda">Produto</label> </div> <div class="input-field col s2"> <input placeholder="Digite a quantidade" name="quantidade_produto_venda" type="text" class="validate"> <label for="quantidade_produto_venda">Quantidade</label> </div> </div>' ); 
}); 

$('#cadastra_venda').click(function(){

  $.ajax({

    url:"cad_venda.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:$('#venda').serialize(),

    success:function(data){

      alert(data);  
      $('#venda')[0].reset();  
    }  
  });  
});  
});   
</script>
```

E o php:

```
<?php

$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($conecta, 'narguile');

$produto_venda = count($_POST['produto_venda']);

if($produto_venda > 0){

    for($i=0; $i<$produto_venda; $i++){

        if(trim($_POST["produto_venda"][$i] != '')){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `vendas`(`desconto`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["produto_venda"][$i])."')";  
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        }
    }

    echo "Data Inserted";  
} else {

    echo "Please Enter Name";  
}

?>
```

Comment: Jovem, os erros citados são no PHP. Vc colocou na pergunta o HTML e o JavaScript. Tem que resolver os erros lá no PHP.

Comment: Cade a linha 13 do seu cad_venda.php

Comment: Pessoal, desculpa, esqueci de colocar o cad_venda.php... malz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou `$conecta` e depois utiliza a `$connect`. Corriga este trecho que a principio vai funcionar.

**Início do código**

```
$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

**Meio do código (Com problema)**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `vendas`(`desconto`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["produto_venda"][$i])."')";  
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

**Correção**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `vendas`(`desconto`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $_POST["produto_venda"][$i])."')";  
mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
```

Comment: po, deu certo, cara, valeuzão....

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro "erro" não é exatamente um erro, é uma notícia, uma espécie de aviso. Só está dizendo que uma variável é indefinida, isto é, você não atribui valor algum a ela. Para sumir com esse "erro" basta colocar o supressor de erros "@" antes da variável, ex "@$var".

O segundo erro, diz respeito a função mysqli_real_escape_string(), aparentemente estás passando parâmetros de forma errada, confira neste link como fazer uso dessa função: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

O terceiro "erro" também é uma notícia, basta usar o supressor de erros.

O quarto e último erro também é um problema de passagem de parâmetro, confira aqui como usar função mysql_query: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

Ao contrário do que está pensando, o erro não é no JS, mas sim no PHP.

Comment: Obg, foi mal, eu esqueci de colocar o php, mas acabei de colocar